# Schnappen + dative

Tags: meaning

I have heard the following sentence in the German TV series "How to Sell Drugs Online (Fast)":

- Schnapp ihn dir, Papa!

Context: a police officer has just received an anonymous tip about a drug dealer at his home and his daughter says the sentence above.

"Schnapp ihn, Papa" means "get/catch him, dad", but I don't understand what the dative pronoun "dir" expresses in this sentence. I would literally translate it to "Get/catch him for you, dad", but that sounds odd. Or is "sich schnappen" just a synonym of "schnappen" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct that we are dealing with the reflexive form *sich etw./jmdn. schnappen*. It is roughly a synonym of the plain *etw./jmdn. schnappen*, but it puts emphasis on the catcher of the thing/person getting caught. (In cases where the final receiver of the caught thing/person is not the catcher, one would rather not use the reflexive form.)

Comment: See [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/schnappen#d-1-2-1). Verbs that take reflexive dative pronouns are unusual but still frequent enough to learn their grammar. According to my notes another one is *ausdenken*.